# pandas - select last n rows of dataframe with respect to an attribute

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks as below:

```
id, date, target
1,2016-10-24,22
1,2016-10-25,31
1,2016-10-27,44
1,2016-10-28,12
2,2016-10-21,22
2,2016-10-22,31
2,2016-10-25,44
2,2016-10-27,12
```

Given the dataframe above, I want to select last 2 rows of ids to make a df2, and another df1 with the rest.

## df1

```
id, date, target
1,2016-10-24,22
1,2016-10-25,31
2,2016-10-21,22
2,2016-10-22,31
```

## df2

```
id, date, target
1,2016-10-27,44
1,2016-10-28,12
2,2016-10-25,44
2,2016-10-27,12
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) for creating `df2`, then get [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) of original with `df1` index and select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) rows from `df` - this is `df1`:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id').tail(2)
print (df2)
   id        date  target
2   1  2016-10-27      44
3   1  2016-10-28      12
6   2  2016-10-25      44
7   2  2016-10-27      12

print (df.index.difference(df2.index))
Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

df1 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df2.index)]
print (df1)
   id        date  target
0   1  2016-10-24      22
1   1  2016-10-25      31
4   2  2016-10-21      22
5   2  2016-10-22      31
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.groupby('id').tail(2)`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html

Comment: @Join Zwinck Thanks. But I edited my question. Can you answer my question again?

Comment: @Mansumen: Please take some time to try what I suggested, then try working on the code yourself to do the rest.  Note that you don't have to use `groupby` necessarily--maybe you'll find it easier to use another approach.  Give it a try.